# SQL Duplicates Query

Tags: sql, duplicates

The table is as follows:

```
id  name
1   tom
2   bob
3   tom
4   tom
5   harry
```

I'm looking for a query that would result in the following:

```
id    name    duplicateposition
1     tom     1
2     bob     1
3     tom     2
4     tom     3
5     harry   1
```

So duplicateposition for the first tom is 1, for the second tom is 2, and for the third tom is 3. The first bob is 1 and the first harry is 1. Is there an easy query to do this?

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT id, name, count(id) from table
```

I'm a little new to sql so that is my best shot.

Comment: Why am I getting thumbs down? I'm asking a legitimate question.

Comment: Those are down votes (hover your mouse over the down arrow). Your legitimate question shows no effort/attempts made. There's no code provided to help you with. It's unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: I see. I'll improve it

Comment: Great! It will also be helpful if you provide the platform you're using.

Comment: ..."platform" in this context meaning "SQL product (and its version)".

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following. It partitions the data by name and assigns a number within the partition. Forgot to mention I did this in SQL Server 2012.

```
select *, 
  row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as DuplicatePosition
from test
order by id
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6459f/5)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic self join that works on most databases (although if you have access to window functions you should use them instead as they're generally faster)

```
select t1.id, t1.name, count(t2.id) duplicateposition
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 
    on t2.name = t1.name
    and t2.id <= t1.id
group by t1.id, t1.name
order by t1.id
```